# Hiding hidden documents and excluding file extensions from a directory in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, directory, hidden

I was searching around the internet and found some solutions but they don't seem to work in my case and I don't know why.
I list all files in the working directory which are .xls files. Now since I'm working with an older version of Office I want to exclude the .xlsx files and also all temporary files but this doesn't seem to work. I tried:

```
 FileAttributes fileAttribute = File.GetAttributes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.xls")
   .Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".xlsx") || !name.Contains(@"\~$") 
   || (fileAttribute & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0).ToArray();
```

Now I tried it without the first line and with " name.Attributes " since " fileAtrribute "but he can't find it. I also tried to search for "?.xls" but then he doesn't list any files. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic issue with:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.xls")
   .Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".xlsx") || !name.Contains(@"\~$") 
   || (fileAttribute & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0).ToArray()
```

you want ands, not ors..

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.xls")
   .Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".xlsx") && !name.Contains(@"\~$") 
   && (fileAttribute & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0).ToArray()
```

However, your fileattribute is checking the directory, not the file.

So you actually want

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.xls")
   .Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".xlsx") && !name.Contains(@"\~$") 
   && (File.GetAttributes(name) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, your `||`'s should be `&&`'s. You want to exclude files where the name doesn't end with xlsx AND it doesn't contain ~$ AND where it's not hidden.

Secondly, your check for the hidden property looks incorrect. Currently you are grabbing the attributes of the *folder* and then comparing that with each file. You really want to get the properties of each file.

In summary, you need:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.xls")
.Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".xlsx") && !name.Contains(@"\~$")
&& (File.GetAttributes(name) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 0):

Since you call Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.xls") you have already excluded .xlsx and temporary files.

Comment: Excuse me, my bad. It also provides files with xlsx extension.

Comment: I think it does because the xlsx is still xls in 8.3 filename

Comment: I still get .xlsx files and temporary files which are hidden.